# ListPicker with conditional selection

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction

I am reading data from a SQL Database and want to manually sellect multiple rows.
ListPicker works very nicely, the only added complication is that I need to not only select the records, but also visually explore the relationship between rows and then occationally add to my selection based on relationship.

As a concrete example, say I have this:

```
dataImport = {{"Unique Number", "Customer", "Re-order", "Comment" , "Amount"},
              {"1001", "cust a", "No", "Comment 1" , "1234"}, 
              {"1002", "cust a", "Yes", "Comment 2" , "200"}, 
              {"1003", "cust b", "No", "Comment 3" , "290"}, 
              {"1004", "cust c", "No", "Comment 4" , "1000"}, 
              {"1005", "cust b", "Yes", "Comment 5" , "876"}};
```

I then can easily get: (lets ignore the formatting for now ...)

```
              ListPicker[Dynamic@selectList, dataImport]
```

I need some functionality where I can select multiple rows - as is the default ListPicker functionality.  But I also want to be able to say right-click (or click on an embedded tick box for a record if that customer has a re-order, then those re-orders will be shown in a popup window - with the possibility of then selecting those records so that they are also added to selectList.

I have tried adding a column containing Checkbox[ ] - problem is

- ListPicker only allows for the selection of complete rows and does not
  register selection of anything within a row.
- Each Checkbox[] would need an unique variable name, and the number of unique names will be determined by the SQL query, and I may do multiple queries to trim the list down by customer or amount.

Any advice or pointers? Since there can be say 1000 rows in my selection (which I will then further refine to about say 100) the solution needs to be responsive.

Comment: Can you `Map` `ListPicker` to columns within rows?

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about general concept but maybe you can use this **minimal example** and extend/adjust to your needs:

```
Grid[{{
   ListPicker[
    Dynamic[selectList, (selectList = #;
                         re = Select[selectList, #[[3]] === "Yes" &]) &],
    dataImport]
   ,
   Dynamic @ If[TrueQ[re === {}],
                "",
                {"Include previous orders of " <> #2, 
                 Button["+", selectList = Union@Join[selectList, 
                               Select[dataImport, Function[s, s[[2]] === #2]]]]
                } & @@@ re // Grid
     ]
   }}]
```

> [image]